# Searchkick: Remove documents when unable to find original record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, elasticsearch, kibana, searchkick

To take the example from another question

```
product = Product.find(10) 
   `raise_record_not_found_exception!'
product.nil?
=> true

product = Product.search "*", where: {id: 10}, load: false
product.count
=> 1
```

How do I remove the document without a clean wipe?

Thanks

Comment: I'm unclear what you are asking exactly. Let me try to describe what I think you're asking and see if it's correct: You have some records in table A - some of which refer to another record in table B... and sometimes the record in table B no longer exists? and if that's the case you want to delete the record in table A ? you want to do this for all records of table A?

Comment: @TarynEast - Let me see if I can clarify for you My project is pulling data from another database manually due to sensitivity. As we pull that data we create/edit the documents then index them for our use later. Sometimes the original database puts the record (Product) into a status we are unable to query therefore losing the current status of that record. My database is unable to query the record and therefore cannot delete it using the method described above. I need a way to reach into the index, identify the correct document, and delete it in case the record never becomes query-able.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If your index is out of sync with your database and you don't want to do a full reindex, you can do:

```
missing_product = Product.new
missing_product.id = 10
Product.search_index.remove(missing_product)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is done by [default](https://github.com/ankane/searchkick#stay-synced) in Searchkick, unless you removed this record by use [some methods](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_callbacks.html#skipping-callbacks)  that skipped callback.

Quote from Searchkick:

> There are four strategies for keeping the index synced with your
>   database.
>
> Immediate (default) Anytime a record is inserted, updated, or deleted
>
> Asynchronous Use background jobs for better performance ...